# pci device id is different in vm when using passthrough

Tags: virtualization, openstack, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to set up SRIOV for a network card on Ubuntu 18.04
I seem to have done the IOMMU configuration correctly and I can add a PCI device to a VM without errors, however I am facing a problem where the guest does not see the PCI ID of the device as the ID that the hosts sees. This ends up in the host not knowing what kind of device it is and doesn't load network drivers.
All the guides I have seen state that the VF ID would be the same in host and guest but mine look like this:
Host:

> 81:00.4 Ethernet controller: Solarflare Communications SFC9020 10G Ethernet Controller (Virtual Function)

Guest:

> 00:06.0 Ethernet controller: Solarflare Communications SFC9020 10G Ethernet Controller (Virtual Function)

The guest correctly identifies that 81:00.4 is a network device and i can see all the details in 'ip link' and 'ip address' but the guest doesn't seem to know what to do with 00:06.0

The physical functions are up and all the virtual functions are also up and have MAC addresse on the host so everything seems fine in terms of driver config.

> enp129s0f1:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
>
> link/ether 00:0f:53:07:91:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> vf 0 MAC 0e:f0:f0:07:ba:11, spoof checking on, link-state auto
>
> vf 1 MAC 01:d0:0b:a1:1a:d5, spoof checking on, link-state auto
>
> vf 2 MAC de:ad:0c:0b:a1:70, spoof checking on, link-state auto
>
> vf 3 MAC 11:5e:ab:a5:5a:55, spoof checking on, link-state auto

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and how to do this properly?

Comment: Those are the PCI bus numbers, not the pci.id. To see the pci.id, run: `lspci -nnk`

Comment: I see this in the VM: 00:05.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Solarflare Communications SFC9020 10G Ethernet Controller (Virtual Function) [1924:1803]
 Subsystem: Solarflare Communications SFC9020 10G Ethernet Controller (Virtual Function) [1924:6206]
but when i try to check ifconfig or ip addr i see nothing. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Was a stupid question. The bus ID of the device is defined in the VM descriptor so there is nothing strange here. The issue I am having is related to the driver and not the bus ID.